# Display/hide image with zoom in/out

Tags: unity, c#, image

After spending a while looking through the forums, I haven't been able to find a thread that deals with transforms on an image.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is display and hide an image at the start of a level in a game I'm working on. The image should start out large and with 100% transparency, then shrink to a certain size within the camera bounds with no transparency, idle for a second, then fade back out the way it came.

How would this be done programmatically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like a fairly straightforward use of the `Image.color` property's `a` alpha transparency field, and the `localScale` property of its transform. How have you tried implementing this behaviour so far in your C# script?

Comment: From my search online, I was able to find out how to change the opacity and scale of an image, but not over time.. I thought about creating some sort of loop that would incrementally decrease the opacity and scale, but I wasn't sure how.

Comment: Hint: Update() is already a loop that cycles once each frame.

Comment: As @DMGregory mentioned that local scale and Image. Color would do the job but to my taste and simplicity, I would probably use DoTween (Free Asset on Asset store). As it will help you a lot in department of animation. But if you need this animation only then using Dotween is overkill so then you may use localScale and color by using IEnumerator. For more about IEnumerator: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html